# express js URL cleanup

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I create a rout that get user full details from the DATABASE(mongoDB).

Router

```
router.get('/user/:userid/:name', getUrl, function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({_id: req.params.userid})
  .exec(function(err, user) {
     if (err) { return next(err); }
     if (!user) { return next(404); }
     res.render('........');
 });
});
```

for instance i can access this router with this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/6465667/username
```

but what i realy want is this

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/username
```

Is there a way of hiding the user ID in the URL

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove `:userid` from your route and use the name to lookup your database. Ensure your username is unique otherwise you might receive the wrong user details.

```
router.get('/user/:name', getUrl, function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({name: req.params.name})
  .exec(function(err, user) {
     if (err) { return next(err); }
     if (!user) { return next(404); }
     res.render('........');
 });
});
```

Comment: the unique value i have in my database is the userid is there a way can hide it without removeing it from the URL